# Flutter Can I take a classes diagram of all classes in Flutter framework? Like UML diagram

Tags: flutter, class-diagram

Can I take a classes diagram of all classes in Flutter framework core? Like UML diagram...

I want to see what class is extended from which one. Because, there are a lot of files in framework core.

I think, it would be very clear to see the class diagram of framework.

Comment: You want to see a diagram of the flutter framework or of your flutter project? And what do you expect to gain from doing this? most of the framework looks like [this](https://www.emanprague.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Flutter_diagram-widgetclass.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @h8moss thanks for answer and link. Exactly, I want to see whole diagram of Flutter framework. the picture you send on link is true one. But, it is a small part of Flutter framework.